# i want to create a stored procedure in sql that select certain rows in a table and then apply input condition on it

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-function

i want to make a store procedure or a function that select certain rows from column and then allow the user to update another column in the same table, the user should be allowed to enter the input value after the select process

```
alter PROC AcceptReject
@department as int,@result as bit

as
begin
select*
from Job_Seeker_apply_Job
where hr_response = 1 and department=@department
update Job_Seeker_apply_Job
set manager_response =@result
```

the user at the beginning should enter department number which is int value then after the selection process the user should be able to update a column called manager_response for the selected rows only

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Comment: what do u mean by tag dbms

Comment: Database server software. For example MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server or IBM DB2.

Comment: I think you are confusing the application layer with the data layer. The end user does not have direct access to a stored procedure and the procedure is not able to display an entry form to capture user input.

Comment: by the user i mean when i execute the procedure